# Missing a step?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a basic math function and change the contents of a `<p></p>` element but when I click the button, it does nothing.

I know it's something trivial but I thought this would work.

What am I missing?

HTML

```
<button onclick="doMath()">Click</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
function doMath() {
var total = 6/2(2+1);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: What is `6/2(2+1)` supposed to be? `6/(2*(2+1))`?

Comment: You're missing a basic debugging step. [Open the browser's JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and look at the error messages.

Comment: Yes you are missing a important thing '*'. Browser doesn't understand Math shorthand. So 2(2+1) will be considered as a function with name 2 and parameter is 2+1. Hence the issue. Try using 6/2*(2+1)

Comment: Adding this to the function still does nothing.
    console.log("This is the total" + total);

Comment: @alexk JS doesn't understand "distributive properties". I had never written a math equation like that in coding, but JS can't imply multiplication. It has to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function doMath() {
var total = (6/2*(2+1));
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doMath()">Click</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: I guess JS doesn't understand a distributive property? If I do `var total = (6/2(2+1)); ` it renders nothing

Comment: @Brandon Javascript follows Javascript syntax, not math. `6/f(2+1)` would be completely ambiguous, is that a function call or a variable you want to multiply?

Comment: @deceze that math problem result is what I want to set the variable total to.  I figured it was something stupid. Thanks for the quick replies!